# Universal instantiation another question why couldn't?

Tags: logic

something like this:

$ \exists x: p(x) \Rightarrow \forall x: p(x)  $

$ \neg \exists x: p(x) \vee \forall x: p(x) $

$ \forall x: \neg p(x) \vee \forall x: p(x)$

So if i use here rule : universal instantiation my form turns from satisfied to tautology why. Why? Why use here UI is wrong and i  shouldn't use here it?

$ \neg p(a) \vee p(a) $

Comment: Hi it's not really clear to me what you're asking. Could you rephrase your question?

Comment: done, main question is why when i use UI here, my form turns from satisfied form to tautology form?

Comment: I think you misunderstand "universal instantiation".  For that, you need one $\forall$ applying to the whole thing.

Comment: You still need a lot more prose to explain what the purpose of your formulas are and how they relate to each other, before you have something resembling an understandable question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Every quantifier has a scope. For example, the scope of $\forall $ in $\forall x: p(x)$ is $p(x)$,  and the scope of $\forall $ in $\forall x: (p(x) \vee \neg r(x))$ is $p(x) \vee \neg r(x)$.

When you apply **UI** to a formula in order to "get rid" of a quantifier, you can apply it *only to the scope of this quantifier*.  Also, when you apply **UI** to a formula, the $\forall$ has got to be the "main" quantifier, that is the quantifier whose scope is the entire premise (formula).

So in your example, if you start with $\forall x: \neg p(x) \vee \forall x: p(x)$ then you can't apply **UI** since there is no $\forall$ quantifier whose scope is the entire formula.

You can, for example, derive $\neg p(a) \vee p(a)$ from $\forall x:( \neg p(x) \vee p(x))$ but not $\forall x: \neg p(x) \vee \forall x: p(x)$.

Answer (score 2):

You cannot apply **UI** to :

> $(∀x \ ¬p(x)) \lor (∀x \ p(x))$.

**UI** licenses the derivation of $\phi(a)$ from $\forall x \phi(x)$ but $(∀x \ ¬p(x)) \lor (∀x \ p(x))$ is **not** equivalent to : $∀x(¬p(x) \lor p(x))$.

Consider the domain $\mathbb N$ of *natural* numbers ($0$ included) and interpret the predicate $p(x)$ as $x=0$. In $\mathbb N$ is obviously *true* that $\forall n \ [\lnot(n=0) \lor (n=0)]$ but it is *false* that : $\forall n \ \lnot (n=0) \lor \forall n (n=0)$.